# How to achieve transaction across an AWS S3 upload and an ElasticSearch update?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, transactions

### Problem

Is there a way to achieve transactionality between S3 and another database like ElasticSearch?

**What I'm trying to do is to upload an object to S3 and save his identifier to ElasticSearch in an atomic way.**

For the backend where logic exists, we are using Java with Springboot.

### From AWS docs

I saw that this is a common pattern recommended by AWS, but they mention that you need to handle on our own the failures:

*"You can also store the item as an object in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) and store the Amazon S3 object identifier in your DynamoDB item."*

*"DynamoDB doesn't support transactions that cross Amazon S3 and DynamoDB. Therefore, your application must deal with any failures, which could include cleaning up orphaned Amazon S3 objects."*

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html

Comment: That documentation is correct, you can't have a transaction across S3 and another service, you must be prepared to handle abandoned objects.